# dyniamically assign attributes python

Tags: python, attributes

Im not sure if this is possible.

i have a dict that looks something like this:

```
 metadata = { "string": "value1", "string2": "value2"}
```

And i have a object that  has attributes and the ability to create new attributes.

```
this
```

I then would like to be able to something like this

```
 for arg, value in metadata.items()
  this.arg = value
```

i would like this loop to translate to:

```
 this.string = "value1"
 this.string2 = "value2"
```

is this possible?

Comment: Use `setattr(object, key, value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `setattr`.

```
setattr(this, arg, value)
```